# Why am I unable to scale a 4-second 60 fps clip down to exactly 1 second?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, pts

I'm currently using the **setpts** filter to speed up or slow down different clips and accuracy is very important to me ( context: I'm concatenating these into a final clip that needs to be perfectly in sync with a separate video.) I've been using this as a general approach:

```
setpts=(targetDuration/totalFrameCount)*N/TB" -r targetDuration/totalFrameCount
```

While it's fairly accurate most of the time, I'm wondering if I can get better results. For example, if I attempt to scale a 4-second 60fps clip down to exactly 1 second, i.e.:

`ffmpeg -y -i clip_4sec.avi -filter:v "setpts=(1/240)*N/TB" -r 240/1 clip_4sec_scaled_to_1sec.avi`

I actually end up with a 992ms clip. Does anyone know why this happening? From my understanding, as long as the target duration is a multiple of frame duration ( 1/60 seconds ) this shouldn't be an issue, correct?

Is there a better approach I can take to improve the accuracy?

Note: FWIW I already double-checked that the input clip has an actual frame count of 240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is 60 fps, and its timebase going into and out of the setpts filter is 1/60. This should be set to 1/240 before PTS is altered.

```
ffmpeg -y -i clip_4sec.avi -filter:v "settb=1/240,setpts=(1/240)*N/TB" -r 240/1 clip_4sec_scaled_to_1sec.avi
```

There's likely a bug here with the implementation of `-r` w.r.t. VFR muxers like AVI.

Comment: Once again, you nailed it :) I've been relying on lossless AVI so far for my side project, just because it runs faster, compared to lossless h264 MP4. But now I'm wondering if I should reconsider, since the VFR can sometimes be a bit tricky to use.